# Docker building fails: returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile1

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER ME
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools \
&& apt-get install inetutils-traceroute \
&& apt-get install iputils-ping \
&& apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

Dockerfile2

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER ME
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
RUN apt-get update apt-get install iputils-ping
RUN apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

Dockerfile3

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER ME
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN apt-get update apt-get install iputils-ping
RUN apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

I tried all the above flavors of my dockerfile but every time I get the same error :

```
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools && apt-get install inetutils-traceroute && apt-get install iputils-ping && apt-get install xinetd telnetd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Someone posted a working answer and deleted it before I could accept it...

Comment: Your problem is that `apt-get install` requires interaction if you don't pass in the `-y` option, which is why it fails as there's nothing to interact with. Please read [best practices for writing docker files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) also, to hint as to the right way to write something adding a bunch of packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone posted an answer and deleted it before I could accept it. But here it is -

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER ME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
net-tools inetutils-traceroute \
iputils-ping xinetd telnetd
```

This works!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use key -y for apt-get or apt  managers, on docker side.
For example:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt -y install net-tools
```

Without -y, apt-get asks a clarifying question - "are you sure you want to install this?". Without answer docker droped installation with code 1. The issue in here.